# How to design same-sized objects which fill their parent?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have three buttons in my android app which are arranged vertically in a linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />

            <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The buttons should be same-sized and at the same time fill their parent. 
Currently I do it programatically (geting the screen height and setting the buttons height. 
Is there any way to do this task directly in xml?

Answer (score 1):

Use `layout_weight` attributes (see [Google documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)), as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Button 2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Button 3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Using `orientation` attribute in LinearLayout will display your child views in horizontaly or verticaly, combined to `layout_weight`, you can say to your child view to take a sort of "percentage" of the parent container.
To use it, you have to specify the `width` or `height` to `0dp` (regarding the orientation).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **layout_weigth**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button 
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />

            <Button 
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `layout_weight` properties to each `Button` in xml like :

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```